# Use variable inside regex

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the variable label

```js
const label = 'test'
```

and the regex

```
{ name: /test/i }
```

What I want is know if I can use the variable `label` inside the regex, something like this

```js
{ name: `/${label}/i` }
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Use this syntax : `new RegExp(label, 'i')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you use a variable in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-use-a-variable-in-a-regular-expression)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use variable in regex, use:

`` new RegExp(`${label}`, 'i') ``